# Hibernate ~ RESTful return the set of an object

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, set

I'm trying to get the Set inside another Object.
Example:

I am returning a list of forums, but in those forums it contains some threads. How do I get those threads when I call the function:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response findAll() {
    List<Forum> forums = new ArrayList<>();

    Forum forum = new Forum();
    WebAccount account = new WebAccount("", "", "", Gender.MALE, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    forum.setAccount(account);

    List<ForumThread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

    ForumThread thread = new ForumThread();
    thread.setAccount(account);
    thread.setId(1);
    thread.setName("sweg");
    thread.setDescription("LOLOL");

    forum.setThreads(threads);
    forum.setId(1);

    Forum forum1 = new Forum();
    WebAccount account1 = new WebAccount("", "", "", Gender.MALE, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    forum1.setAccount(account1);
    forum1.setId(2);

    forums.add(forum);
    forums.add(forum1);
    GenericEntity<List<Forum>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Forum>>(forums) {};
    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

I would like to know two things:

1. Get all threads but only the ID numbers.
2. Get the whole thread information of every single thread.

Forum class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({})
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="Website_Forum")
public class Forum implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 16)
@TableGenerator(name = "ForumSEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ForumSEQ")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "webaccount_id")
private WebAccount account;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 64)
private String name;

@Column(unique = false, nullable = false, length = 1024)
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinTable(name = "Website_ForumThreads", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "forum_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<ForumThread> threads;

public Forum() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public WebAccount getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(WebAccount account) {
    this.account = account;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public List<ForumThread> getThreads() {
    return threads;
}

public void setThreads(List<ForumThread> threads) {
    this.threads = threads;
}
}
```

Could someone explain me why I am not getting any threads?
This is my JSON output when I call the function:

```
[
  {
    "account": {
      "dateOfBirth": 9223372036854775807,
      "email": "",
      "gender": "MALE",
      "helpId": "9c5ee012-4c35-4c6c-be0f-aa8b383642a5",
      "helpType": "ACCOUNT_CREATE",
      "information": "A new account!",
      "isBanned": false,
      "password": "",
      "permissionGroup": "REGULAR",
      "profilePicture": "/Media/ProfilePictures/default.png",
      "username": ""
    },
    "id": 1,
    "threads": []
  },
  {
    "account": {
      "dateOfBirth": 9223372036854775807,
      "email": "",
      "gender": "MALE",
      "helpId": "590b8ccb-5c96-4044-8e58-424f5d5287c6",
      "helpType": "ACCOUNT_CREATE",
      "information": "A new account!",
      "isBanned": false,
      "password": "",
      "permissionGroup": "REGULAR",
      "profilePicture": "/Media/ProfilePictures/default.png",
      "username": ""
    },
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Show the class `Forum` please

Comment: Updated it, you can now see the whole Forum class

Comment: I don't see any call to `threads.add(thread)`, so the list is empty.

Comment: Oh wauw.... Thanks that solved question 2, is there a way I can only return the ID's of the threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain me why I am not getting any threads?

In your actual code:

```
List<ForumThread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

ForumThread thread = new ForumThread();
thread.setAccount(account);
thread.setId(1);
thread.setName("sweg");
thread.setDescription("LOLOL");

forum.setThreads(threads);
forum.setId(1);
```

You are not adding anything in your `threads` list, you are just creating `Thread` object without adding it to the list and then return this empty `List`.

You should add the created `Thread` object to your list before setting it to the `Forum`object.

```
threads.add(thread); //add the created thred to your List
forum.setThreads(threads);
forum.setId(1);
```

**Edit:**

To answer your second question:

> Get all threads but only the ID numbers.

And to get only the `ID`s of the `Threads` in a  `List` you should create a customised `DTO` object having `Forum` attributes, and a `List<Integer>` to hold only the `ID`s of the `Thread` class, and use a custom code to fill this list.

Comment: Ye I already solved that, thanks a lot though! Do you maybe also have a solution so it will only return the forumthread id?